# Cyberpower UPS - huge drop in battery when switching to battery power

Tags: ups

I just acquired a CyberPower OR1500LCDRM1U UPS device from eBay. It was said to be open box and not used, but I have my doubts.

I have it installed, and am putting a 30% load on the battery. With the 30% load, when the battery is charged 100% it reports that there is 23 min of runtime on it, which seems fair.

However, if I simulate a power failure by pulling out the plug, the battery immediately drops to 60% charge, with a runtime of 12 min of runtime.

I've tried this multiple times with the same result. While I would expect the battery to take a hit when I switch from ac power to battery, I wouldn't expect to see an immediate 40% hit. Does this seem like a unit malfunction or perhaps one (or multiple) batteries are bad?

Comment: CyberPower provides documentation that is typically attached to the battery or the case itself on when the battery was tested.  Do you have that documentation?  If this was truly just an open box that documentation should have been provided by the merchant.

Comment: Nope, nothing was included other than the normal instruction manual.